# How to count unique items in column in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I need help. I can't seem to find the logic behind this code.

I am working on a voting system, and I need to output the results of the votes.

I want to count all of the rows that has a unique name in it and output how many.

My table goes like this.

```
voterid | pres   | vpres | sec   | trea | PIO
---------------------------------------------
1       | John   | Mitch | James | Jack | Eman 
2       | John   | Pao   | Bryan | Jack | Faye 
3       | Kelvin | Pao   | James | Jeck | Faye
```

Output should be

```
Pres   | Votes
--------------
John   | 2
Kelvin | 1
```

Here's my code.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    pres,
   (SELECT COUNT(pres) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT pres FROM tblVote AS Votes)) AS Votes
FROM tblVote
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are just looking for a simple `GROUP BY` query:

```
SELECT pres, COUNT(*) AS Votes
FROM tblVote
GROUP BY pres
```